# Remove referenced duplicate entries from XML file

Tags: xml

After hours beating my head against the wall, I decided this is [probably] not the job for a mere shell script.

There's a bug on Google Earth that makes loading KML files very slow: for almost every new Placemark you create, it creates 2 new Styles, references both Styles on a StyleMap in `<styleUrl>`, and then references the StyleMap on the Placemark:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>

    <StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>

    <Placemark>
        <LookAt>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <LookAt>
            <altitude>1</altitude>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>0</gx:drawOrder>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

- *sh_ylw-pushpin* and *s_ylw-pushpin_hl* are duplicate entries with just a different name (id). Each is referenced on a different StyleMap. The same applies to *sn_ylw-pushpin* and *s_ylw-pushpin*.
- If we remove the duplicate Styles and fix their references (eg. `s/\<sh_ylw-pushpin\>/s_ylw-pushpin_hl/`), we will be left with duplicate StyleMaps too, so we should repeat the deduplication on them too.

Summarizing, what I need is to get rid of the duplicate entries from the XML file (leaving just one), and update all references of the removed entries to the one that was left.

Comment: I would either use a language which can parse the xml (such as perl, python, ruby, etc), or use `augeas`.

Comment: @Patrick Any ideas on __how__ to do this? A simple code snippet for me to get started, since I don't know python, perl or ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to know what you want to do I would suggest trying to do this using the command line tool `xmlstartlet`. It looks like you can delete entries from the KML/XML file programmatically.

#### References

- [man page for xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)
- [tutorial on using xmlstarlet](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2005/11/linux-20051115/2/)
- [IBM Developer Works Tutorial on xmlstartlet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-starlet/index.html)

**NOTE:** The IBM tutorial references the tool as `xml`, just swap that out with `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Removing the entries with xmlstarlet seems possible if I now their ids, but do you know if there's any way to find the duplicates with it?

Comment: I don't see exactly how to delete the duplicates. I did come across this snippet which uses another tool called `xmlproc` to remove duplicates using xsl to do the deleting. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=929783

Comment: I ended up with a shell script that loops through the whole file, saves every style on a separate file, runs fdupes to find duplicates, removes entries by name with xmlstarlet, and then their references with sed. Styles were reduced from almost 15,000 lines to about just 500!